# Linear Algebra - Linear Combinations

Tags: linear-algebra

We are asked the following:

The span of $$v_1,v_2,…,v_r$$ can be the whole $$V,+,⋅$$ or a subset of $$V,+,⋅.$$ Give an example of each situation.

The span is denoted

$$span v_1, v_2, ..., v_r $$

The whole is stated above as $$V, +, .$$

The whole means, 'the whole vector' e.g., everything. The span is just particular conditions that the vectors $v_1, v_2, ..., v_r$ must satisfy in order to belong to $V, +, .$

An explicit example may include, but is not limited to:

Let $v_1 =(x_1, y_1,z_1)$ such that $x_1z_1 = 0$, $v_2 = ( x_2 ,y_2 ,z_2 )$ such that $x_2z_2 = 0$, where entries are real numbers .
Let $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$.
$v_1 + v_2 = (x_1, y_1,z_1) + (x_2 ,y_2, z_2 ) = (x_1 + x_2 , y_1 + y_2,z_1 + z_2 )$ is not in the set.

Is this on the right track? Will this answer the question?

Comment: 100000 apologies, for I cannot produce the span latex =(

Comment: Is $V$ sepcified? In any case I assume you should give explcit examples.

Comment: $V$ is a general case. The kind one may find in an introductory course pertaining to Linear Algebra. It contains fundamental operations for the subspace of vectors e.g., adding subtracting and multiplying

Comment: I still assume you should give an explcit example.

Comment: Indeed, as it says "give an example". So you have to find an example where the span of $v_1,\dots, v_r$ is $V$ and one where the span of $v_1,\dots,v_r$ is a subset of $V$ (maybe $v_1,\dots,v_{r-1}$ ?).

Comment: What is $c$ for in your example?